# How exactly does Sencha Touch wrap the native app?

Tags: android, ios, touch, extjs

When I compile my web app to a native iOS and Android app, how will it work? Will it be a regular web view that runs my app, which is in my server? Or it will place all the images, HTML and CSS files inside folders in the app project on Xcode and read them locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latter. It will copy all files to the device, and run a webview which will load from the local directory. Think of it like you have some web files on your PC and point your browser to localhost to access them. It will load all the local pages/images even when offline, but you will face errors connecting to external resources unless online. Plenty of web apps are made without ever touching the developer's servers, also many times a simple restful solution will suffice.